# Can we remove NSPopover's arrow in macOS using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

When I am displaying a `NSViewController` as `NSPopover`, I am getting an arrow with this `NSPopover`. My question is how we can remove this arrow from NSPopover?

Comment: But this link is related to iOS App,iam checking for a solution related to MacOSX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I remove the arrow in the popover view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801860/can-i-remove-the-arrow-in-the-popover-view)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any Apple, built-in functionality to do so. However, it is possible to mimic the functionality of NSPopover and have more advanced control. For example, the SFBPopovers library seems a very good choice and has a setDrawsArrow: method: https://github.com/sbooth/SFBPopovers

Here is a picture from the example application with a popover with no arrow coming from the "Toggle Popover" button.
[image: SFBPopovers]