# iOS SwiftUI Need to Display Popover Without "Arrow"

Tags: ios, swiftui, popover

I need to display a list of selections for the user to choose. I have examined Menu, .contextMenu(), and .popover(). While all three of these work fine, I cannot display what I need to show or I cannot style them to meet design needs. For example:

- Menu

  - Only accepts a StringLiteral argument. I need it to accept a View.
  - List only displays Label with text and image. I need it to accept a View. When I convert the View to an Image it clips to top and bottom.
- .contextMenu()

  - I can run this on a view, but the List has the same Label problems when I attempt to display an image.
  - Only displays list with longPress. It needs to be a tap.
- .popover()

  - Performs everything I need for display except that in iOS it displays an arrow pointing to the parent view. I cannot have an arrow.

At this point it looks like popover is the most favorable option if I can set it up so the arrow is not displayed. From what I understand from the documentation only macOS is allowed to hide the arrow.

Is there a way to show .popover() without the arrow in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always build your own popover. The following techniques could be used:

- Show the popover as the top layer in a `ZStack`.
- Use `.matchedGeometryEffect` for positioning.

Here is an example to show how it can work:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    enum PopoverTarget {
        case text1
        case text2
        case text3
    }

    @State private var popoverTarget: PopoverTarget?
    @Namespace private var nsPopover

    @ViewBuilder
    private var customPopover: some View {
        if let popoverTarget {
            Text("Popover for \(popoverTarget)")
                .padding()
                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                .background {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .fill(Color(white: 0.95))
                        .shadow(radius: 6)
                }
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: popoverTarget,
                    in: nsPopover,
                    properties: .position,
                    isSource: false
                )
        }
    }

    private func popoverPlaceholder(
        target: PopoverTarget,
        xOffset: CGFloat = 0,
        yOffset: CGFloat = 0
    ) -> some View {
        Color.clear
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: target, in: nsPopover)
            .offset(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
    }

    private func showPopover(target: PopoverTarget) {
        if popoverTarget != nil {
            withAnimation {
                popoverTarget = nil
            } completion: {
                popoverTarget = target
            }
        } else {
            popoverTarget = target
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Text 1")
                    .padding()
                    .background(.blue)
                    .onTapGesture { showPopover(target: .text1) }
                    .background { popoverPlaceholder(target: .text1, yOffset: 70) }
                    .padding(.top, 50)
                    .padding(.leading, 100)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

                Text("Text 2")
                    .padding()
                    .background(.orange)
                    .onTapGesture { showPopover(target: .text2) }
                    .background { popoverPlaceholder(target: .text2, xOffset: -40, yOffset: -70) }
                    .padding(.top, 100)
                    .padding(.trailing, 40)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)

                Spacer()

                Text("Text 3")
                    .padding()
                    .background(.green)
                    .onTapGesture { showPopover(target: .text3) }
                    .background { popoverPlaceholder(target: .text3, yOffset: -70) }
                    .padding(.bottom, 250)
            }
            customPopover
                .transition(
                    .opacity.combined(with: .scale)
                    .animation(.bouncy(duration: 0.25, extraBounce: 0.2))
                )
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            popoverTarget = nil
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: This is a very much better way of showing the popover. Worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way of showing `.popOver` without an arrow in `SwiftUI`. Because it will show any of the `Edge` arrow definitely. You can check the declaration:

```swift
public func popover<Item, Content>(item: Binding<Item?>, attachmentAnchor: PopoverAttachmentAnchor = .rect(.bounds), arrowEdge: Edge = .top, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> Content) -> some View where Item : Identifiable, Content : View
```

But you can achieve this using `UIKit`. For UIKit I'd refer this question: [Can I remove the arrow in the popover view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801860/can-i-remove-the-arrow-in-the-popover-view)

Comment: That's what I figured would be the answer. Thanks.